# Is ARIMA and Random Walk a Nested model?

Tags: time-series, arima, random-walk, nested-models

I have confused about the Radom Walk. If a model restrict some parameter as 0 and the two regressions  are the same, which is the Nested model. But in ARIMA model versus Random Walk model, the random walk  just the last oberservation even not a estimate$.$ In this situation,are the two model nested$?$ I have a simple example below$.$

- $Y_{t} = C + \phi Y_{t-1} + \varepsilon _{t}$--------------------------$Model1$
- $Y_{t} = C + \phi Y_{t-1} + \phi Y_{t-2} + \varepsilon _{t}$---------------$Model2$
- $Y_{t} = Y_{t-1} + \varepsilon _{t}$----------------------------------$Model3$

The $Model1$ and $Model2$ are the nested. But what about the $Model1$ and $Model3$ $?$

Comment: You can obtain model 3 by setting $C = 0, \varphi = 1$ which makes it a nested model, as long as you include the nonstationary ARIMA models (as $|\varphi| < 1$ is not respected)

Comment: @Maximillian Aigner: I understand what you are saying and agree with you. But the term "nested" can be a little misleading because it usually implies that the nested model can be obtained by estimating the larger model and testing whether the coefficients are the values  that you explained they need to be. Unfortunately, this approach doesn't work in the random walk case ( where the random walk is nested )  which is why all the dickey fuller machinery and variance ratio testing arose. So,  you are  correct. Model 3 is nested with Model 2 but the usual implications of nesting don't apply.